# Are there reasons not to use product of vectors as dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The dot product of two vectors is defined as following:
$$
\langle \vec v, \vec u \rangle = 
\left<
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\dots \\
v_n
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\dots \\
u_n
\end{pmatrix}
\right>
= v_1 \cdot u_1 + v_2 \cdot u_2 + \dots + v_n \cdot u_n
$$

Still the multiplication of transposition of $\vec v$ and u gives:
$$
\vec v^T \cdot \vec u = (v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n) \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\dots \\
u_n
\end{pmatrix}
= v_1 \cdot u_1 + v_2 \cdot u_2 + \dots + v_n \cdot u_n
$$

so the result is the same!

It may be just a silly observation but I'm just surprised because I have never seen using it.

Are these two notations the same thing or is there something important in their definitions that don't allow interchanging them?

Comment: It's used a **lot**.  For example, there would be no other way to make sense of the denominators [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient).

Comment: Thank you, but I should say in my linear algebra course I have never seen the relationship of my question (even if it's quite trivial).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a row vector represents a *linear form*, i.e.  a lineap map from $\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R$. So they're different in essence.

However, to the *vector* $\vec v$, you can associate the *linear map* 
\begin{align*}\varphi_{\vec v}\colon\mathbf R^n&\longrightarrow\mathbf R\\\vec u&\longmapsto \langle\vec v,\vec u\rangle \end{align*}
and in this association, the column vector that represents $\vec v$, becomes its transpose. So it is quite normal the results are the same.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, they are identical. If you would like to see the equality in practice, consider the following:

**Theorem:** If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with real coefficients, then there exists an $n\times m$ matrix $B$ such that 
$$(Ax)\cdot y = x\cdot(By)$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

*Proof:* By your equality:
$$(Ax)\cdot y = (Ax)^Ty = x^TA^Ty = x\cdot(A^Ty).$$
So, $B=A^T$.

Comment: thank you for proving this example!

Comment: @Blex Happy to help!